# Scaling surface reflectance product in ENVI?

Tags: raster, envi

I am using ENVI 5.4, specifically 'Data Stretch' tool in a bid to scale down my Landsat 8 OLI surface reflectance product values. I have populated the dialogue box (as below) and compared the histogram of the resultant raster with the original one.

However, there is anomaly noticed in its values (see histogram). I anticipate same histogram stretch however this is not the case.

[image]

[image]

Why there is such discrepancy in the results?

Comment: Try with band math `b1*0.0001` and compare results

Comment: I have alternate options as you suggested but intending to know what might be wrong with this tool and is there any way to get acceptable results while using this tool.